# Статическая библиотека и флаги для CRT

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Очень неожиданный для меня вопрос. В Visual Studio есть проект статической библиотеки (`*.lib`). Так вот, на что тогда влияет флаг для выбора CRT, а именно `MD/d` или `MT/d`? С одной стороны по названию понятно, что это статическая библиотека, но размер все-таки зависит от этих флагов.

**PS:**
Все спокойно собирается с любыми флагами, но еще не пробовал запускать на других машинах.

Comment: [Здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx) читали?

Comment: А почему возникает такой вопрос? Небольшие вариации в размере вполне ожидаемы - соглашения вызова могут меняться,  инициализационный код, еще что-то...

Comment: @alexolut, суть в том, что логически - это все статика, т.е. вместо создания объектов в dll и адресов в lib, мы все заносим в lib. Логично, что статическая линковка должна запихнуть все lib почти все, в то время как динамическая только от проекта. Но, если делать с MT (есть еще 2 зависимости от других lib), то размер уменьшается). А с MD увеличивается.

Comment: Мне кажется вы путаете статическую библиотеку и статическую линковку, статическая библиотека вовсе не обязательно должна статически линковаться с рантаймом

Comment: @goldstar_labs, я просто не делал никогда статические библиотеки.  Но возникает другой вопрос: почему с динамической сборкой получается больше размер файла.

Comment: С динамической *линковкой* размер файла обычно выходит как раз меньше, потому что код функций находится в линкуемой dll

Comment: @VTT, вот это меня и смутило, с MT у меня получается больше на 2 МБ.

Comment: @MrBin, все правильно, потому что /МТ - это статическая линковка

Comment: @goldstar_labs, там я опечатался. С /MD  у меня больше на 2 МБ.

Comment: @VTT: Мне кажется, автор вопроса говорит о сборке *своей библиотеки*. В этом случае библиотека времени выполнения в любом случае *не будет* включатся в библиотеку автора, неважно какой флаг использован. В библиотеку автора будет добавлена только *ссылка* на версию библиотеку времени выполнения, независимо от того, какой способ линковки выбирался. Незначительные вариации в размерах возможны, но это мелочи. Возможно, что в варианте с DLL библиотека получается чуть больше. Ничего удивительного в этом нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Опции MD/d и MT/d указывают тип подключения стандартной библиотеки, это никак не связано с типом проекта. Проект статической библиотеки определяет только то, что **ваши** модули при линковке будут подключаться статически. CRT при этом может подключаться и динамически. Собственно, большинство программ и использует смешанную линковку - что-то подключается статически через .lib, а что-то через dll. Функции WinAPI, например, всегда подключаются динамически.

Что касается вопроса "почему с динамической сборкой получается больше размер файла" - так ведь сборки еще нет. Реально CRT будет подключаться только при сборке исполняемой программы (или dll), а статическая библиотека содержит только ссылки. Ссылки на функции dll занимают чуть больше места, так что это нормальная ситуация.

Дополнение:

Не совсем понимаю смысл вопроса насчет описания библиотек в зависимостях. Библиотека сама должна включать себя в зависимости. Делается это, например, так:

1) В проекте библиотеки создаются 4 конфигурации - MD, MDD, MT, MTD (или 8 - 4 для x86, и 4 для x64), которые создают библиотекм MyLibMD.lib, MyLibMDD.lib, и т.д.

2) В начале главного файла заголовка библиотеки - то есть некоего MyLib.h, который будут подключать пользователи вашей библиотеки, - пишется вот такая конструкция:

```
#ifndef _LIB
    #ifdef _DLL
        #ifdef _DEBUG
            #pragma message( "MyLib included (Debug DLL)" )
            #pragma comment(lib, "MyLibMDD.lib")
        #else
            #pragma message( "MyLib included (Release DLL)" )
            #pragma comment(lib, "MyLibMD.lib")
        #endif
    #else       // _DLL
        #ifdef _DEBUG
            #pragma message( "MyLib included (Debug Static)" )
            #pragma comment(lib, "MyLibMTD.lib")
        #else
            #pragma message( "MyLib included (Release Static)" )
            #pragma comment(lib, "MyLibMT.lib")
        #endif
    #endif  // _DLL
#endif  // _LIB
```

На этом все. Чтобы подключить вашу библиотеку, достаточно написать в программе

```
#include "mylib.h"
```

Есть еще один небольшой момент - если библиотека может использоваться из другой библиотеки, то символ _LIB использовать нельзя - в библиотеке-клиенте он тоже определен, и соответственно зависимости будут отключены. Нужно определить свой символ (какой-нибудь MYLIB) в stdafx.h своей библиотеки или в настройках проекта, и использовать его вместо _LIB.

Comment: Ну, а что тогда делать, когда количество библиотек начинает давить и приходится каждую описывать в зависимостях. Например для mariadb, чтобы использовать С++  надстройку необходимо подключить libmariadb.lib, mariadbclient.lib и mariadbcpp.lib. Мне придется все эти библиотеки перекомпилировать с MT, чтобы в моей надстройке уже было все в готовом виде и не пришлось подключать ещё 3 другие?

Comment: @MrBin: поскольку ответ включает пример кода, дополнил основной ответ.